# Can you group data with similar written column headings on xlswrite, matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab

Very new to matlab and still learning the basics. I'm trying to write a script which calculates the distance between two peaks in a waveform. That part I have managed to do, and I have used xlswrite to put the values I have obtained onto an excel file.

For each file, I have between about 50-250 columns, with just two rows: the second row has the numerical value, and the first has the column headings, copied from original excel files I extracted the data from.

Some of the columns have similar, but not identical, headings, e.g. 'green227RightEyereading3' and 'green227RightEyereading4' etc. Is there a way I can group columns with similar headings, e.g. which have the same number/colour in the heading (I.e.green227) and either 'right eye' or 'left eye', and calculate an average of their numerical values? Link to file here: >https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezpyjr3raol31ts/SampleBatchForTesting.xls?dl=0>

```
    >[Excel_file,PathName] = uigetfile('*.xls', 'Pick a File','C:\Users\User\Documents\Optometry\Year 3\Dissertation\A-scan3'); 
    >[~,name,ext] = fileparts(Excel_file); 

    >sheet = 2;
    >FullXLSfile = [PathName, Excel_file];
    >[number_data,txt_data,raw_data] = xlsread(FullXLSfile,sheet);


    >HowManyWide = size(txt_data);
    >NumberOfTitles = HowManyWide(1,2);
    >xlRangeA = txt_data;


    >Chickens = {'Test'};
    >for f = 1:xlRangeA; %%defined as top line of cells on sheet;
    >Text = xlRangeA{f};  
    >HyphenLocations = find(Text == '-');
    >R = HyphenLocations(1,1) -1;
    >Chick = Text(1:R);
    >Chick = cellstr(Chick);
    >B = length(Chick);
    >TF = strncmp(Chickens,Chick,B);
    >if any(TF == 1); %do nothing
    >else 
    >Chickens = {Chickens;Chick};
    >end
    >end
```

Here also is a link to the file that is created when I run my entire script. The values below the headings are the calculated thickesses of the tissue I'm analysing. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4p6iu9kk75ecyzl/Choroid_Thickness.xls?dl=0

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the different characters are located at the very end (or the very beginning) of the heading, you can go with *strncmp* buit-in function and compare only part of the string. See more [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html). But please, provide some code and a part of your excel file. It would help.

Also, if I am not mistaken, you are saving all the data into excel and then re-call it again in order to sort it. Maybe you should consider saving only the final result in excel, it will save you some time, especially if you want to run your script many times.

EDIT:

Here is the code I came up with. It is not the best possible solution for sure, but it works with the file you uploaded. I have omitted the unnecessary lines and variables. The code works only if the numbers of each reading have the same amount of digits. They can be 4 digits as long as every entry has 4 digits. Since in each file you have waves of the same color, the only thing that you care about is whether the reading was recorded with the left or the right eye (correct?). Based on that and the code you wrote, the comparison concerns the part of the string that contains the words "Right" or "Left", i.e. the characters between the hyphens.

```
[Excel_file,PathName] = uigetfile('*.xls', 'Pick a File',...
'C:\Users\User\Documents\Optometry\Year 3\Dissertation\A-scan3'); 

sheet = 1; 
FullXLSfile = [PathName,Excel_file]; 
[number_data,txt_data,raw_data] = xlsread(FullXLSfile,sheet); 

%% data manipulation
NumberOfTitles = length(txt_data); 
TextToCompare = txt_data{1};
r1 = 1;                            % counter for Readings1 vector
r2 = 1;                            % counter for Readings2 vector
for ff = 1:NumberOfTitles          % in your code xlRangeA is a cell vector not a number!
    Text = txt_data{ff};           
    HyphenLocations = find(Text == '-');
    Text = Text(HyphenLocations(1,1):HyphenLocations(1,2));                    % take only the part that contains the "eye" information
    TextToCompare = TextToCompare(HyphenLocations(1,1):HyphenLocations(1,2));  % same here
    if (Text == TextToCompare)
        Readings1(r1) = number_data(ff);  % store the numerical value in a vector
        r1 = r1 + 1;                      % increase the counter of this vector
    else
        Readings2(r2) = number_data(ff);  % same here
        r2 = r2 + 1;
    end
    TextToCompare = txt_data{1};  % TextToCompare re-initialized for the next comparison
end
mean_readings1 = mean(Readings1); % Find the mean of the grouped values
mean_readings2 = mean(Readings2);
```

I am positive that this can be done in a more efficient and delicate way. I don't know exactly what kind of calculations you want to do so I only included the mean values as an example. Inside the `if` statement you can also store the `txt_data` if you need it. Below I have also included a second way which I find more delicate. Just substitute the `%%data manipulation` part with the part below if you want to test it:

```
%% more delicate way
Text_Vector = char(txt_data);
TextToCompare2 = txt_data{1};
HyphenLocations2 = find(TextToCompare2 == '-');
TextToCompare2 = TextToCompare2(HyphenLocations2(1,1):HyphenLocations2(1,2));
Text_Vector = Text_Vector(:,HyphenLocations2(1,1):HyphenLocations2(1,2));
Text_Vector = cellstr(Text_Vector);
dummy = strcmpi(Text_Vector,TextToCompare2);
Readings1 = number_data(dummy);
Readings2 = number_data(~dummy);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here's what I have so far: Chickens={'Test';}; 

for f = 1:NumberOfTitles; %NumberOfTitles selects the first row of the excel file
Text = xlRangeA{f}; %xlRangeA is pretty much the same as NumberOfTitles. Don't know why I renamed it. 
    HyphenLocations = find(Text == '-'); % finds hyphens in data    
R=HyphenLocations(1,1) - 1;
Chick=Text(1:R);

Chick = cellstr(Chick);
B = length(Chick);
TF= strncmpi(Chickens,Chick,B);


if any(TF == 1)
    % do nothing
else
    
    Chickens={Chickens;Chick};
end    


end

Comment: %I'm not getting very far, because 'Text = xlRangeA{f}' returns text from just the last cell in row 1, therefore everything else focuses on that one outcome. I've tried taking it out of the loop, rearranging it, trying 'Text = char(xlRangeA) but it comes up with big list of the titles and I can't pinpoint the specific characters I need to. Example of titles (all in row 1): 'green123 - Right eye - Reading 1'; 'green123 - Right eye - Reading 1'; 'green123 - Right eye - Reading 3' etc etc, with 4-6 readings per eye, and possibly 30 or more specimens (green 123, green 124 etc) on each spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks again for helping, and I'm really sorry if I sound thick. Trying to (mostly) teach myself and have had a very short time frame and a very non-mathematical brain.

Comment: @M. Berry Can you please edit your initial question and add the code there, so we can see it in a code format? It is really difficult to read it like this. Just follow the instructions, they are very clear. Just edit your post and add all the new information there.

Comment: Hi there, think I've put it on there, hope it's a bit more legible

Comment: How is `xlRangeA` defined? Can you please attach one of the excel files that you have created with the distances between the peaks, that way I can try to test your code.

Comment: Have added the link to a sample file and I think the necessary code

Comment: Please do let me know if you find a solution. And thanks again for your help

Comment: I took a look the excel sheet and your code. Unfortunately I didn't have time to write my own code yet. A few remarks so far:

- Try to use less variables, not so much to make your code faster, but for the code to be less confusing for you.

- If the rest of the files are like the one you uploaded, I think you should search for the second Hyphen not the first since you wanna compare the left/right eye as well. Then the `if` should check whether not all but a big percentage of the characters are the same since you need to group the similar (not necessarily identical) inputs.

Comment: I haven't fully come up with the best way to code it yet but maybe these hints will help you in the meantime.

Comment: Also, is every file containing waves of the same color like the one you uploaded? So can we just divide the data of each file to 'right eye' and 'left eye' ?

Comment: Hi Nico. Thanks so much for your response. Noted about throwing in fewer variables. And yes I agree - much better to search for the second hyphen. And in answer to your question about the files - yes, all waves are labelled green, with a number (corresponding to the specimen number - although there are over 200 altogether). For each specimen number, there are readings for both the right and left eye. Data for several specimens on each excel file. I hope that makes sense. We're talking quite a large pool of data to get through, although i

Comment: still plan on selecting each file one by one from the folder. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Are the numbers always 3 digits?

Comment: No, sometimes they're 4 digits as well. Sorry, super inconvenient

Comment: I included some code in my answer that worked for me.

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for your response. It may not be perfect but it's far better than the solution I've come up with, and what's more is that I now know exactly where I need to tweak it to make it perfect. I wish I had a better way of thanking you than just a few words on a thread - can't tell you how much stress it's been causing! Really appreciate the time you've given to help out, so grateful for your effort! Thank you again from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: NIce to hear that worked for you. Now that you know how the code works you can write it in fewer lines if you want (e.g. in the second method you skip the `dummy` variable and do the comparison in one line: `Readings1 = number_data(strcmpi(Text_Vector,TextToCompare2))`. Also please mark the answer as "accepted" so that in the future other people know it worked.